in elliptic curve over finite field we get two values of y for each x now how can we draw elliptic curve using these points?

as we can see in the image one side elliptic is wrapping around torus in clockwise and other in anticlockwise direction my question is when we find two values of y for each x how can we know which y is on which line the one with clockwise rotation or anticlockwise rotation ? the image of torus is from youtube video(https://youtu.be/mFVKuFZ29Fc?feature=shared) so i dont know how they plotted the elliptic curve.now i wanted to draw elliptic curve for y^2=x^3+7 mod 29 but don't know (3,11)and (3,18) which will be on which line. 

I just wanted to know when we draw elliptic curve on the points how can we know which point is on which line one which wraps around torus in clockwise or on the other line which wraps around torus in anticlockwise direction like if i start from point (0,6) then which will be the next point (3,11) or (3,18) for the curve y^2=x^3+7 mod 29

Like this one?

Nothing special, since the rectangle is mapped into torus.

The curve $y^2=x^3+a\,x+b$ with $x$, $y$ in the field $\mathbb R$ of reals has  infinitely many point. It is continuous (with for some choices of parameters 2 disjoint pieces). It is symmetrical with respect to the X-axis: if $(x,y)$ belongs to that curve, then so does $(x,-y)$. It is natural to distinguish the part of the curve with $y>0$, the symmetric part with $y<0$, and the 1, 2 or 3 point(s) with $y=0$. That curve extends indefinitely to the right, top and bottom thus we can only represent it partially. For the question's $y^2=x^3+7$:

The "curve" with the same equation in the finite field $\mathbb F_r$ for prime $r$ has finitely many points, so it's noting like some continuous and smooth flowing line without sharp angles. It's symmetrical with respect to the X-axis in the same sense that if $(x,y)$ belongs to that "curve", then so does $(x,-y)$. Since $r$ is odd there is a least objectionable analog in $\mathbb F_r$ to $y>0$: we can define $y>0$ holds when $y$ has an integer representative in $(0,r/2)$; that is for $y\in\{1,2,\cdots,13,14\}$ when $r=29$. A nice thing with that definition is that $y>0$ if and only if neither $y=0$ nor $(-y)>0$, just as in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb Z$. That definition allows to distinguish the part of the "curve" with $y>0$, the symmetric part with $y<0$, and the at most 3 points with $y=0$.
So  we can put points of the discrete "curve" above, below, and on the X axis (with negative representatives for the $y$ in the second kind) according to $y>0$, $y<0$, or (for at most 3 points) $y=0$. Perhaps we can also color points in three colors, like we did in the continuous curve.

It you ask me, that's OK, even though we see no continuous line(s) per the curve's equation with the discrete points falling on that line. Upon close examination of the question's first figure it does not manage to do that for all the discrete points that it shows. And I don't see that would be possible in general for there is usually few or no point(s) on the real curve with both their coordinates integers.

If we really want to do such mapping of discrete to continuous points on curves with the same equation, in a way preserving the elliptic curve group's operation, we can at least in theory: we pick a generator point of the discrete curve, map it to some point of the real curve with the same order (that exists and can be found precisely for moderate $r$ at least), and we let the group operation define the mapping of all the other points. This way, the geometric construction of point addition on the continuous curve works to compute point addition for the discrete curve. Problems with that:

Except for very small $r$ the resulting graph is unreadable or not all discrete points show, at least with linear scale
The coordinates of a discrete point have no simple relationship to the coordinates of the respective continuous point
I don't see how the coloring of discrete points we defined previously could match the natural coloring of the continuous curve.

I'll try to make a picture, but don't hold you breath. It will have some similarity to this, with different scale and labels.
